# Hamas and Palestinian Authority reproduction policies

Tags: israel, palestine, hamas, population

Yasir Arafat had been on the record of making [statements like](https://ground.news/article/yasser-arafat-the-womb-of-the-woman-will-be-our-strongest-weapon-against-the-zionists):

> The womb of the woman will be our strongest weapon against the Zionists!

The long-term implication is that the Israel's position vis-à-vis Palestinians would become unsustainable when the Palestinian population significantly outgrows the Jewish one. The short-term implications are high population density in the West Bank in Gaza, the fact that nearly half of the population are children (which translates in high proportion of children deaths during military conflicts), and significant part of the population are unemployed young men, whose best chance for success is joining Hamas or a similar organization, while young women are seemingly condemned to just bear more children. (See [*Demography and the Palestine Question*](https://www.palquest.org/en/highlight/297/demography-and-palestine-question-ii) and [*Demographics of the State of Palestine*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_State_of_Palestine).)

Questions:

- Beyond Arafat's statements, is there a deliberate demographic policy by Palestinian Authority or Hamas, directed at increasing birth rates (e.g., subsidies for big families, child support, etc.)
- Have any women rights organizations or pro-Palestinian organizations commented on this visions/policies?

**Background**
Data on Fertility rates in the region can be found [here](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.TFRT.IN?locations=ZQ&most_recent_value_desc=true) with West Bank and Gaza on the second place after Yemen. Here is a visual representation (based on the data from 2013, but still more or less correct):
[image]

([image source](https://books.openedition.org/ifpo/13234))

It is worth noting that these fertility rates do not necessarily correlate with the poverty level, as [Gaza and West Bank GDP per capita, although low, is higher than that in Syria, Yemen, Morocco or Tunisia](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.CD?locations=ZQ&most_recent_value_desc=false):
[image]

([image source](https://www.cartoprodig.cnrs.fr/en/indicateur-carte/en_economy/en_eco_gdp-per-capita/))

Comment: What would you count as "policies to increase birth rates"? Things like the unconditional illegality of abortion in both Gaza and West Bank certainly lead to higher birth rates in a way. As does poverty (a known correlation). Do you count such or only explicit birthrate-raising policies?

Comment: @Tom what I want to discern is the *intent* - just because they let people breed does not constitute a policy. If they enforce (or do not enforce) certain rules of Islam more than others to achieve population increase - this is a different story.